# Decimal to any base (up to 16) in java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have been working on a recursion algorithm that should ask for a decimal value and be able to convert to any base up to 16. I was able to implement it and have it working for up to base 9 as this doesn't involve any letters. The part I'm struggling with is the printing of the letters for after base 9.

For example, 1567 in base 16 is 61F.
I have written code that SHOULD work in theory but it is returning big fat zeros. I have attempted to add breakpoints to work out what is going wrong but I've still had no luck.
I have declared strBase as a static private variable.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong in the code and what I need to fix?

Very much appreciated,
a very tired uni student.

```
public static String toBase(int bType, int decimal) // base not working correctly
{
    int rem, base;
    char[] hexDex = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    
    if (decimal == 0)
    {
        base = decimal % bType;
        strBase = Integer.toString(base);
    }
    else
    {
        rem = decimal % bType;
        strBase = strBase + hexDex[rem];
        toBase(bType, decimal/bType);
    }
    return strBase;
```

Comment: Your first `if(decimal == 0)` always results in calculating `base = 0 % bType;`.

Comment: Hint: what is happening to the result of this call?  `toBase(bType, decimal/bType);`

Comment: "I have declared strBase as a static private variable." - debug what happens to `strBase` if you have multiple calls to `toBase` (hint: the value will be replaced - how do you get the previous value back?)

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the base case and replaced it with  if(decimal != 0) and it works. Wow, I've been staring at this for hours wondering why it's not working. Thank you so much!